# Sender based redirection on Postfix

Tags: email, postfix

I'm running postfix on Debian, receiving email for `my.com`, and I would like all incoming emails from `sender.com` to be delivered to `jack@my.com`, regardless of the original recipient.

Emails from other domains still need to go to the original recipient.

Is this possible/easy to set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/postfix-users/message/286106).

> You can use sender-dependant aliases like that:
>
> main.cf:
>   smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
>
> sender_access:
>   sender.com redirect jack@my.com